# Windows security vs Linux

Tags: windows, security

Most people argue that Linux are safer because generally you don't log with root privileges
so a virus can't do much damage(or damage at all)
Can't the same concept be applied in Windows as well, since there is the option of "Standard Accounts".
So wouldn't windows be as secure as Linux?

Comment: This is essentially asking for a comparison of two highly different systems and will elicit a large degree of conjecture and speculation rather than actual fact.  While facts may play a part in the answers there are too many answers to definitively answer this kind of question.

Comment: To be fair though, the same principle *is* applied in Windows in corporate environments.  For home users who prefer more freedom on their system there us UAC.

Comment: I always suspected Linux was considered more secure than Windows due to added flexibility in system layout - not in user privileges. For example, Linux functions perfectly well when /boot is unmounted after system startup, so this particular part of the system becomes uncompromizable (/boot on SD card which may be removed or even locked away after system startup). I am not aware of any solution to make this happen on Windows, and keep Windows running.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to that aspect, yes. I mean, if you use windows with a limited account there isn't much damage a virus can do without using privilege escalation attacks (bypass security restriction in order to get administrative privileges from a common account).